# Plotly: How to customize markers depending on differences in a series?

Tags: python, plotly, linechart, marker, plotly-python

I have this kind of line+marker graph plot. I am creating this chart with plotly go scatter. what I want is that, to minus two numbers in the list, if the difference is greater than 5 than it colors the marker with black.
as shown in image
y=[7,9,**14**,16,17,**10**,10]
in this case 14-9=difference is 5, 10-17=abs 5

```
def setcolor(x):
         if x[1]-x[0]>=5
         return 'black' 
         else:
         return 'orange'
fig = go.Scatter(y=df['data'], 
                        mode='markers+lines', name='data',
                        marker = dict(color=list(map(SetColor, df['data']))),
                        line=dict(color='rgb(200,200,200)'
                           ))
```

but it's not working. I used this approach.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up your absolute differences in its own series in your dataframe and then use an extra trace with `mode=markers` to illustrate the points that satisfy your criteria. The main benefit compared to using annotations for the same markers is that you now can use plotlys interactivity to easily hide or show the highlighted markers. The code snippet below will produce this plot:

[image]

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'No':[5,7,12,11,5,10,9,15,16,13],
                    'Name':['nab', 'cab', 'mun', 'city',
                            'coun', 'nwa', 'kra', 'ihr', 'nor', 'del']})


#df.index = list('abcdefg')
diffs=df['No'].to_list()

# find differences in list
diff=[abs(j-i) for i, j in zip(diffs[:-1], diffs[1:])]
D=[np.nan]
D=D+diff

# check if difference is greater than 5
D = [x if x >= 5 else np.nan for x in D]
df['diff']=D
df['ix']=df.index
df2=df.dropna()

# plotly setup
fig=go.Figure(go.Scatter(y=df['No'], x=df['Name'],
                         mode='lines+markers'))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(y=df2['No'], x=df2['Name'],
                          mode='markers', marker=dict(color='black', size=14)))

fig.show()
```

Comment: @ZamanAzam You can use any index. Run `df.to_dict()` and include the output in the question and I may take another look at it.

Comment: @ZamanAzam **Images are not very useful as long as I don't know for sure what caused the errors. Again, a sample of your data would be much more helpful**

Comment: here is code picture.but i am unable to display 'name' column as xaxis instead of indexes

Comment: @ZamanAzam OK. But for future questions, please **do not** share data and code as images. Plots are OK, but then as screenshots embedded in the question using the `Image` button in the question toolbar.

Comment: @ZamanAzam None of the issues you've experienced should be a real problem. But let's continue our communications in StackOverflow chat. Just click [this link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218790/room-for-vestland-and-zaman-azam)

Comment: @ZamanAzam I've edited my answer to be able to handle the datasample in your last screenshot. It does not matter that *what* the index is; string or integer, as long as the values are internally unique. So I hope this it satisdactory at last. If you find the time tomorrow we can still talk in chat.

Comment: is it possible to just update markers colour, not add trace separately?